# In Postgresql how do I get localtime as the TimeZone to work on FreeBSD?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

`PostgreSQL`: 9.4
`FreeBSD`: 11.2

When I set my `TimeZone` parameter in `postgresql.conf` to `localtime` I receive the following error when trying to start PostgreSQL.

```
service postgresql restart
<2022-06-02 11:18:27.612 EDT> LOG:  invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "localtime"
<2022-06-02 11:18:27.613 EDT> FATAL:  configuration file "/usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf" contains errors
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

During my searches I've found [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/26280.1458583397%40sss.pgh.pa.us) correspondence which seems to indicate that /etc/localtime should be a symlink. Mine isn't so I tried changing it to a symlink and it still didn't work as I get the same error as above.

```
mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.bak
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Yellowknife
shutdown -r now
ls -la /etc/localtime
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  35 Jun  2 11:04 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Yellowknife
```

Is it possible to get `TimeZone` set to `localtime` working on `FreeBSD`?

Note that I also found [this](https://serverfault.com/a/923556/961423) discussion where it mentions creating a `symlink` to `/etc/localtime` in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`. I tried that as well and it did not work as I still get the same error as above.

Using `pg_config --configure` I see that it was not configured with `--with-system-tzdata`. Is this a requirement to using `localtime`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you configured PostgreSQL, it does not use the operating system's time zone database, but its own copy, which is located in `pg_config --sharedir`. So your symbolic link has no effect.

You'd have to create that symbolic link in PostgreSQL's copy of the timezone database, but the correct solution is different: set `timezone` to `America/Yellowknife`.

Do not use unsupported PostgreSQL versions.